# Testng in selenium ------suggest which annotations are suits

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I have created Project(Page Object Model) in Eclipse like this

Project name 
     Package 1
        src
        bin
     package 2
       src
       bin

In package 1 contains, element description and method 
In package 2 contains,

BaseScript.java  ---------
preconditon

```
webdriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("url");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        LoginPage l=new LoginPage(driver);
        l.setusername("");
        l.setpassword("");
        l.LoginBut();
```

Postconditons

driver.quit();

I have T1.java,T2.java and converted into.xml(testng.xml) and Run using Testng that file(testng.xml)

I want to execute all testcases at a time with one browser but i've got when i execute testcases it's calls BaseScript.java

Answer (score 1):

`Selenium` is a tool which controls the browser/website like a user. It simulates a user clicking through the pages. Knowing the functionality of your web application, you can setup your tests. Now run set of test cases together i.e. Test Suite. `TestNG` gives this capability to manage test execution.

I suggest you to read this simple [**tutorial**](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-testsuite/) to setup TestNG suite of tests.

> I want to execute all testcases at a time

Selenium Grid is a part of the Selenium Suite to run tests in parallel. You setup the driver in base classs

```
public class TestBase {

protected ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> threadDriver = null;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

    threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fp);
    dc.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.firefox().getBrowserName());
    threadDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), dc));
}

public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return threadDriver.get();
}

@AfterMethod
public void closeBrowser() {
    getDriver().quit();

}
}
```

An example of sample test would be:

```
public class Test01 extends TestBase {

@Test
public void testLink()throws Exception {
    getDriver().get("http://facebook.com");
    WebElement textBox = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Name']"));
    // test goes here
}
}
```

You can add more tests in similar way as above

```
public class Test02 extends TestBase {

 @Test
 public void testLink()throws Exception {
    // test goes here
 }
}
```

TestNG Configurations:

***testng.xml***

```
<suite name="My Test Suite">
 <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="./testFiles.xml" />
 </suite-files>
```

***testFiles.xml***

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test runs" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

<test name="T_01">
  <classes>
     <class name="com.package.name.Test01" ></class>
  </classes>
</test>

<test name="T_02">
  <classes>
     <class name="com.package.name.Test02" ></class>
  </classes>
</test>

<!-- more tests -->

</suite>
```

Comment: I know how to convert testng.xml but i've confusion on annotations